# Using directory list, assign input option and print

Tags: python

very new to python and have a "python block" I'm trying to solve.  I want to query a specific linux directory for its files (could be any number of files in directory), then display (print) the files list for user input selection; like the following:

```
Please choose your option:

1 - somecode.py

2 - somefile.txt

3 - someotherfile.j2
```

Where the above filenames were pulled from the directory and the option number is prefixed and displayed for the user to select.  So far I can pull the directory list and print it, but getting stuck pulling the list into a user input function for proper display and user selection.

if I just pull a print the files in the directory it looks good, but having trouble with the part about prefixing a option varibale to the list and displaying for user input.

```
for filename in os.listdir('./templates'):

    print(filename)
```

it looks like this:

```
cisco_tmpl.j2

juniper_tmpl.j2

nxos_tmpl.j2
```

Many hours trying various ways to pretty this up and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just store `listdir`  and index the file name from the list with the users input

```
files = os.listdir('./templates')

for index,file in enumerate(files):
    print('{num} - {dir}'.format(num=index+1,dir=file))

x = input('choose a file')

print(files[x-1])
```

Comment: Thanks DJK.  This would be the perfect way, but I can't get it to break out of the for loop to print the listing and then offer the user input... I tried a dozen ways to get it to break from the for loop, just not happening.

Comment: Why would you “break” out of the for loop to print the listing? That’s what’s happening in the for loop

Comment: When I use your code as is and run, it outputs: "  File "./test1.py", line 15
    x = input('choose a file')
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax"  But if I break it out of the loop and then use the line "x = input('choose a file')" I will display the list and prompt for the input... I input a list number and it returns the file name of the list number selected... which is what I want.... just have to get out of the  loop before it will display the list and the prompt.

Comment: I wrote that on my phone sorry, there’s a `)` missing at the end of the print statement. I edited the post

Comment: Yea, tried that already, it doesn't make a difference.  The only way I can get the print list and ability to run the "x = " is to get out of the for loop.... I can get out while running it in idle, but not programatically.

Comment: DJK... Never mind, your initial script post was accurate.  I somehow lost the second ")" on my own 8-)   Thanks so much, this is a elegant and smooth solution.  Kudos to you!!!

Comment: @badgerdog glad to help :). If this post accurately answers your question, please consider marking it as accepted by clicking the hollow check mark to the left.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add the user selection option before the filenames, try this:

```
file_no = 1

for filename in os.listdir('./templates'):

    print(str(file_no) + "- " + filename)

    file_no += 1
```

And then ask the user which one they want to select:

```
selected_file = int(input("Select a file..."))

if selected_file == 1:

    #do stuff

elif selected_file == 2:

    #do some other stuff

#etc
```

Comment: Very good. Anish  This works, but the number of files in the listed directory will vary on any given reading(listing).  One day there may be 1 file and on another day there may be 30 files.  Is there as way to change the "elif selected_file == " to vray based on the number of files read?

Comment: One more thing, the "filename" associated with the selected option will be used as a variable to pass to another part of the overall script.

Comment: I'm not completely sure about this, but you can do `os.listdir(path)[selected_file]` to get the file you want. Then, you can do whatever you want with this file.